# Material UI Grid off center when has background color

Tags: material-ui

### Grid No Background - centered

Material UI grid looks centered without a background.

[image]

### Grid Background - not centered

When Material UI grid and grid items have a border and background, you can see they're not centered. They are closer to the left. Only the text and elements inside the grid and grid items are centered. The grid and grid items themselves are not centered.

[image]

How would one add a background to the grid so the grid still looks centered?

### [Codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/grid-background-center-issue-material-ui-b4ghpc?file=/demo.js)

```
import React, { useState } from "react";
import { Grid } from "@mui/material";
export default function GridTest() {
  const [hasBackground, setHasBackground] = useState(true);
  return (
    <>
      <div
        style={{
          border: "3px solid purple",
          padding: "40px",
          position: "relative"
        }}
      >
        <h2
          style={{
            position: "relative",
            top: "-50px",
            color: "purple"
          }}
        >
          div
        </h2>
        <h2
          style={{
            position: "relative",
            color: "green"
          }}
        >
          Grid
        </h2>
        <Grid
          container
          spacing={3}
          style={
            hasBackground
              ? {
                  background: "#bbe4c3",
                  border: "3px solid green"
                }
              : { border: "3px solid white" }
          }
        >
          <Grid
            item
            style={
              hasBackground
                ? {
                    color: "red",
                    border: "3px solid red"
                  }
                : { border: "3px solid white" }
            }
            xs={6}
          >
            grid item
            <div
              style={{
                color: "blue",
                border: "3px solid blue"
              }}
            >
              div inside grid Item
            </div>
          </Grid>
          <Grid
            item
            style={
              hasBackground
                ? {
                    color: "red",
                    border: "3px solid red"
                  }
                : { border: "3px solid white" }
            }
            xs={6}
          >
            grid item
            <div
              style={{
                color: "blue",
                border: "3px solid blue"
              }}
            >
              div inside grid Item
            </div>{" "}
          </Grid>
        </Grid>
      </div>

      <button
        onClick={() => {
          setHasBackground(!hasBackground);
        }}
      >
        toggle grid and grid items backgrounds/borders
      </button>
    </>
  );
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Add a div around the grid and give that a background instead.

[image]

### [Codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/grid-background-center-issue-material-ui-solution-wmwn0c?file=/demo.js)

```
import React, { useState } from "react";
import { Grid } from "@mui/material";
export default function GridTest() {
  const [hasBackground, setHasBackground] = useState(true);
  return (
    <>
      <div
        style={{
          border: "3px solid purple",
          padding: "40px",
          position: "relative"
        }}
      >
        <h2
          style={{
            position: "relative",
            top: "-50px",
            color: "purple"
          }}
        >
          div
        </h2>
        <h2
          style={{
            top: "20px",
            position: "relative",
            color: "green"
          }}
        >
          Grid
        </h2>

        <span
          style={{
            position: "relative",
            color: "green"
          }}
        >
          div
        </span>
        <div
          style={{
            background: "#bbe4c3",
            border: "3px solid green"
          }}
        >
          <Grid
            container
            spacing={3}
            style={
              hasBackground
                ? {
                    background: "#bbe4c3",
                    border: "3px solid green"
                  }
                : {}
            }
          >
            <Grid
              item
              style={
                hasBackground
                  ? {
                      color: "red",
                      border: "3px solid red"
                    }
                  : {}
              }
              xs={6}
            >
              grid item
              <div
                style={{
                  color: "blue",
                  border: "3px solid blue"
                }}
              >
                div inside grid Item
              </div>
            </Grid>
            <Grid
              item
              style={
                hasBackground
                  ? {
                      color: "red",
                      border: "3px solid red"
                    }
                  : {}
              }
              xs={6}
            >
              grid item
              <div
                style={{
                  color: "blue",
                  border: "3px solid blue"
                }}
              >
                div inside grid Item
              </div>{" "}
            </Grid>
          </Grid>
        </div>
      </div>

      <button
        onClick={() => {
          setHasBackground(!hasBackground);
        }}
      >
        toggle grid and grid items backgrounds/borders
      </button>
    </>
  );
}
```